# Index query for large data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am working with some traffic data in VB.net using SQL Server. My table name is `[Sim VehRecord]`, columns are:

```
Record ID
Simulation Sec(s)
Vehicle No
Link No
Lane No
Position (m)
Speed (km/hr)
```

Basing on the columns 2, 3 and 6, I would like to fill column 7 for each row.

Sample of traffic data shown here:

```
Record ID     Sim Sec(s)  Vehicle No Link No Lane No Position(m)  Speed (km/hr)  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1        0.80        2        74        1        13.42    
        2        0.80        3        74        2        12.88    
        3        0.80        4        2         1        2.90    
        4        1.00        1        73        1        17.97  
        5        1.00        2        74        1        17.73  
        6        1.00        3        74        2        17.22  
        7        1.00        4        2         1        7.22  
        8        1.20        1        73        1        22.42  
        9        1.20        2        74        1        22.04  
        10       1.20        3        74        2        21.57  
        11       1.20        4        2         1        11.54
```

I have used following code:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_SimVehRecord_VehNo
ON [Sim VehRecord] ([Sim Time (sec)] ASC, [Position (m)] ASC)

UPDATE [Sim VehRecord]
SET [Speed (km/hr)] = (SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(7, 2), 3.6 * COALESCE (([Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)] - (SELECT TOP 1 sv.[Position (m)])) / NULLIF(([Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)] - sv.[Sim Time (sec)]), 0), 0)) 
                       FROM [Sim VehRecord] sv 
                       WHERE sv.[Veh No] = [Sim VehRecord].[Veh No]
                         AND sv.[Position (m)] < [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)]
                         AND sv.[Sim Time (sec)] < [Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)])
```

But I always get an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Error is quite clear... You subquery which used in the update statement returning more than one row and you update set clause expecting 1 row to be returned. You can run select statement separately to see the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query realy return more than one result in 8, 9, 10, 11.

you need the position of the vehicle and the previous position to calc the speed, right?

so i belive you need something like

```
with yourTable as (select * 
from (
values (1, 0.80, 2, 74,  1, 13.42),
(2, 0.80, 3, 74,  2, 12.88),
(3, 0.80, 4, 2,   1, 2.90),
(4, 1.00, 1, 73,  1, 17.97),
(5, 1.00, 2, 74,  1, 17.73),
(6, 1.00, 3, 74,  2, 17.22),
(7, 1.00, 4, 2,   1, 7.22),
(8, 1.20, 1, 73,  1, 22.42),
(9, 1.20, 2, 74,  1, 22.04),
(1, 1.20, 3, 74,  2, 21.57),
(1, 1.20, 4, 2,   1, 11.54)
) V (ID, Sec, Vehicle, Link, Lane, Position)),

pos_and_previous_pos as (
select 
Vehicle, Lane,ID, Sec, Position, 
LAG(Position) over (partition by Vehicle, lane order by sec asc) as previous_pos,
LAG(Sec) over (partition by Vehicle, lane order by sec asc) as previous_sec
from yourTable
)

select id, vehicle, sec, position, 3.6 * isnull((Position - previous_pos) / (Sec - previous_sec), 0) kmh
from pos_and_previous_pos
order by vehicle, lane, sec
```

i did partitioned by lane too, i am not sure if it matters in your use case.

see a working demo here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fdc5982119a56cd6730635f076c286bc

I guess your update would be something like

```
with SimVehRecord as (
select 
[Record ID], [Simulation Sec(s)], [Position (m)], 
LAG([Position (m)]) over (partition by [Vehicle No]  order by [Simulation Sec(s)] asc) as previous_pos,
LAG([Simulation Sec(s)]) over (partition by [Vehicle No] order by [Simulation Sec(s)] asc) as previous_sec
from [Sim VehRecord]
)
select *, (3.6 * isnull(([Position (m)] - previous_pos) / ([Simulation Sec(s)] - previous_sec), 0)) as kmh from SimVehRecord;
```

working fiddle update sample:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ee0c496d930117d632f96fd26440a435

be sure to have a index
[Vehicle No], [Simulation Sec(s)], [Position (m)]

let me know if it helped you..

Comment: Thanks Frederic.. I was taking long time for understanding the logic. Note that, i give more emphasis on processing time. Because, i have almost 5 million data. Previously i applied recursive logic which used to take almost 8 min time to process. With your guidelines i came up the following solution:

Comment: ```
UPDATE [Sim VehRecord]
SET [Speed (km/hr)] = 
(SELECT FORMAT(3.6* COALESCE (([Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)] - LAG (sv.[Position (m)],1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY sv.[Veh No] ORDER By sv.[Sim Time (sec)] ASC))/NULLIF(([Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)] - LAG (sv.[Sim Time (sec)],1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY sv.[Veh No] ORDER By sv.[Sim Time (sec)] ASC)),0),0),'N2','en-us') 
From [Sim VehRecord] sv
Where
sv.[Veh No] = [Sim VehRecord].[Veh No]
And
sv.[Position (m)] < [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)]
And
sv.[Sim Time (sec)] < [Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)]) 
```
But error " returned <1 value"

Comment: WITH SimVehRecord AS (SELECT sv.*, LAG (sv.[Position (m)],1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY sv.[Veh No] ORDER By sv.[Sim Time (sec)] ASC) as prev_posn, LAG (sv.[Sim Time (sec)],1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY sv.[Veh No] ORDER By sv.[Sim Time (sec)] ASC) as prev_time FROM [Sim VehRecord] sv WHERE sv.[Veh No] = [Veh No] And sv.[Position (m)] < [Position (m)] And sv.[Sim Time (sec)] < [Sim Time (sec)]) 
UPDATE [Sim VehRecord] SET [Speed (km/hr)] = (SELECT FORMAT(3.6* COALESCE (([Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)] - prev_posn)/NULLIF(([Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)] - prev_time),0),0),'N2','en-us') From SimVehRecord)

Comment: In the later option the query is executed but all values of Speed (km/hr) column are shown as NULL. Can you please help me in finding out what went wrong. Please note that the second option took only 20 sec to execute. The recursive logic option which took 8 min time for execution is given below:

Comment: UPDATE [Sim VehRecord]
       SET [Speed (km/hr)] =
       (SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,2),3.6* COALESCE (([Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)] - MIN (sv.[Position (m)]))/NULLIF(([Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)] -MIN (sv.[Sim Time (sec)])),0),0)) 
       FROM [Sim VehRecord] sv
       WHERE
                            sv.[Veh No] = [Sim VehRecord].[Veh No]
       And
       sv.[Position (m)] < [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)]
       And
       sv.[Sim Time (sec)] < [Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)])

Comment: @Tariq see this fiddle 

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ee0c496d930117d632f96fd26440a435

a working update in a table with the name and columns similar yours

(sorry updated the fiddle without lane in partition)

Comment: my update was wrong did miss the from .... inner join to_cte...
sorry I was sleepy when wrote the answer

Comment: @Tariq,  Do you already has indexes with columns [vehicle no], [sim time(sec)], [position (m)], right?

Comment: Thanks a lot Frederic...That was excellent effort. This one works now, It takes 28 sec to execute 5 million data. Much better than 8 min. I then tried the following code to determine the density of vehicles. Can you please check whether the  syntax and logic are ok or not?

Comment: UPDATE [Sim VehRecord]
       SET 

                            [Density (veh/km)] =
       (SELECT CAST(ROUND(1000* COALESCE ((COUNT(DISTINCT [Veh No]))/NULLIF((MAX(sv.[Position (m)]) - MIN (sv.[Position (m)])),0),0),0) as int)
       FROM [Sim VehRecord] sv
                            WHERE
             sv.[Sim Time (sec)] = [Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)])

Comment: I then tried to determine the Headway ( longitudinal distance between two vehicles on any particular lane) . The code is given below: The code works fine. But it takes 2 min time to execute. Please note that mt data table has following clustered index column : "Create Clustered Index IX_SimVehRecord_VehNo
ON [Sim VehRecord] ([Sim Time (sec)] ASC, [Position (m)] ASC)"

Comment: And the code for determining Headway (m) is:

UPDATE [Sim VehRecord]
       SET 
       [Headway (m)] = 
       (SELECT FORMAT(MIN(sv.[Position (m)]),'N2','en-us')
       FROM [Sim VehRecord] sv 
       WHERE sv.[Position (m)] > [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)]
       AND
       sv.[Lane No] = [Sim VehRecord].[Lane No]
       AND
       sv.[Sim Time (sec)] = [Sim VehRecord].[Sim Time (sec)]) - [Sim VehRecord].[Position (m)]